# Apply struts interceptor to subset of paths?

Tags: struts2, interceptor

I'd like to apply a Struts interceptor to a subset of paths only.  E.g. only requests whose path start with "/api", for example.

Seems sort of like a no-brainer but so far my google-fu is failing me badly.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/interceptors.html. In struts.xml file we can define multiple packages. Refer the following example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662705/struts2-have-two-packages-in-struts-xml-point-to-dynamic-web-root as @Dave said we can define interceptor stack to particular package level.

Answer (score 3):

Interceptors can be defined per-package, e.g., with a default interceptor. In your example, it would be the package with the "/api" namespace.

The other option is to configure the interceptor(s) per-action, which is irritating.

Comment: Interesting.  Do yuo know of an example somewhere you could point me to?  Thanks.

Comment: @denishaskin An example of what? Every package has its own interceptor stacks, and each can set its own default interceptor-the S2 docs give examples.

Comment: Ah, @suke's answer below was what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

In your struts.xml, you can define a new package

```
<package name="yourpackage" extends="default" namespace="/api">     
    <default-interceptor-ref name="yourInterceptorStack"/>
</package>
```

In your action classes, you can specify the package as follows,

```
@ParentPackage("yourpackage")
public class YourAction extends ActionSupport {
    ...
}
```